# Generating rooms with Node.js / Socket.io

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, socket.io

Some browser games like [agar.io](http://agar.io) and [generals.io](http://generals.io) have a feature in which a player can create a private game room associated with a link. Other players can join the room by going to the same link in their browser. How does this feature work and could I replicate it using Socket.io and Node.js?

Comment: Yes you can and socket.io website has example of it. Which is very simple, why you need to ask it here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some of this is covered in the ["chat" example on the socket.io site](https://socket.io/get-started/chat/).  There are multiple parts to make this work.

1. Put a user into a chat room of a given name.
2. Create some sort of user interface for your users for another user to see existing chat rooms and click on something that tells your server they want to join that room.
3. Create a server request handler to process a user's desire to join a particular chat room.
4. Create a user interface to chat in the room you've joined.
5. When receiving chat text on your server, send it to all other users in that chat room.

In socket.io, your server is what puts a socket.io connection into a room.  It does so by calling `socket.join(roomName)` where `socket` is the socket.io connection of the user that you want to put in the room.  If you want to allow users to create their own rooms, then you'd have to let them specify a room name and then send a request to the server to start that chat room.  The server would then call `socket.join(roomName)` and that chat room would be automatically created.  If you want other users to know that room now exists, you'd have to broadcast to all of them some message of your creation that tells all connected users that a new room has just been created.  This would typically be doing with something like:

```
io.emit('newRoom', roomName);
```

And, all users would have to be listening for the `newRoom` message.

Then, assuming you have some sort of user interface for displaying all the existing rooms you would likely create another message that a client connection can send to the server to express an interest in joining a specific room name such as:

```
 io.emit('joinMeTo', roomName);
```

The server would then listen for the `joinMeTo` message on each client socket and process it:

```
 socket.on('joinMeTo', function(roomName) {
     socket.join(roomName);
 });
```

Some more details are in the above referenced chat demo.  If you get stuck on a specific step, then you can ask a more specific question.

Comment: Thank you! I've been trying to use namespaces but it seems like rooms would work better.

Comment: @SimonHuang - Yeah, namespaces aren't really for chat-type functionality.  I think of namespaces more like pre-defined channels of information and you connect to the desired channel (think of it like a cable TV channel - you tune to the channel that has the info you want).  You don't usually dynamically create namespaces, the way you can/do with rooms.